# Extracting x, y and z coordinates from .las dataset (lidar)

Tags: ascii, coordinates, lidar, lidar-data

I was trying to extract bare coordinates of the points in a pointcloud of a classified (vegetation) .las dataset.

Using Arcgis and looking into the attribute table is not what I'm looking for so I was asking myself, if I can "de-convert" the .las to ASCII or so, to get those coordinates. I hope someone understands my question.

EDIT: I managed to get what I want with a simple toolset of Arcmap 10.2 called `Featureclass Z to ASCII (3d Analyst)`

Answer (score 2):

Though you got you want in Arcmap, there is a free and open source way. To extract XYZ values from a .las file, check out [LAStools](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools), specifically the [`las2txt`](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/blob/master/bin/las2txt_README.md) command:

```
$ las2txt -i mylasfile.las -o mytextfile.txt -parse xyz
```